# Laravel text area validation best practice

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure what kind of validation I should use for comments in E-commerce website that I am currently developing. It is not much I want to validate but I'm worried about security.

So what is the best practice?

My code now looks like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'comment' => 'max:1000',
]);
```

Is it safe to leave it like that?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your needs but I could suggest some

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'comment' => 'required|min:3|max:1000',
]);
```

Comment: Why would you want your comment nullable? Doesn't that mean I can submit empty comment? I don't see the point!!

Comment: Yeah, You are  right, So if it is a comment should have a body, so add required to rules

Comment: the difference between required and nullable restriction is that when the field is set as required the data will never be submitted with the comment being empty. And since you're developing an e-commerce its best practice to let only willing client give comment and not like force the to submit a comment. And that's why I encourage it being nullable.